# AngularFire - New Provider Syntax

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

What is the purpose of these providers, that the `@angular/fire` package add on `ng add` in the `app.module.ts` imports:

```js
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAnalytics(() => getAnalytics()),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
    provideFunctions(() => getFunctions()),
    provideMessaging(() => getMessaging()),
    providePerformance(() => getPerformance()),
    provideRemoteConfig(() => getRemoteConfig()),
    provideStorage(() => getStorage()),
```

What function do they provide? I still need to import the `AngularFirestoreModule` when I want to use the Dependency Injection for `AngularFirestore` to not receive a `NullInjectorError` on it.

Can I just remove them without issue? Why would I keep these imports?

Comment: They should provide the the modules for you. However i think there might have been some name changes So the dependency would be just Firestore. Maybe check what version you have installed.

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen I'm using `@angular/fire@7.4.1`. All the "normal" modules (like `AngularFireAuthModule`) come from `*/compat/*` imports which makes me think they're old. But the Angular Fire Documentation doesn't mention that at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AngularFire 7 came with a new modular SDK](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/version-7-upgrade.md#new-modular-sdk) in addition to the existing one which is now exported via the `compat` import paths.

The ng add schematic adds the module imports for the new SDK. When you use the new SDK module imports, you need to inject different classes to your components, services for it to work (as already mentioned in the comments). Check out the [the samples folder for the modular SDK in the AngularFire repo](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/tree/master/samples/modular) for code examples.

The [docs pages in the AngularFire repo](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/tree/master/docs) are not yet updated with the new modular SDK. There is [a PR open](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/pull/3236) for the new docs with some changes already to the docs pages. You could check out that branch as well.

To answer your questions:

> Can I just remove them without issue?

If you want to keep using the old SDK (via the `compat` imports), then yes. Note, that - as far as I know - [Firebase AppCheck](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) is not available in the old SDK.

> What function do they provide? Why would I keep these imports?

You need them, if you want to use the new modular SDK, which uses the tree-shakable Firebase JS SDK under the hood.